# no suitable constructor found for UnicastRemoteObject()

Tags: java, constructor, rmi

As of javase api 8, `rmic` is deprecated. So generating `stubs` dynamically is preferred by way of exporting objects as:

1. Subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and calling the `UnicastRemoteObject()` constructor.
2. Subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and calling the `UnicastRemoteObject(port)` constructor.

So I first called the `UnicastRemoteObject(port)` constructor but got **compilation error:** `no suitable constructor found for UnicastRemoteObject(int)`
Then I tried calling `UnicastRemoteObject()` constructor and still got the same **compilation error**. What is possibly going wrong?

**EDIT:** My code:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class MyServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote {
    MyServer()throws RemoteException {
        new UnicastRemoteObject(5000);
    }
    //Other methods...
}
```

**Exact quoted error:**

*no suitable constructor found for UnicastRemoteObject(int)
    constructor java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.UnicastRemoteObject() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.UnicastRemoteObject(int,java.rmi.server.RMIClientSocketFactory,java.rmi.server.RMIServerSocketFactory) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)*

My question is, when [`java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html) is present in javase8 api then why is the compiler giving error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Subclassing UnicastRemoteObject and calling the UnicastRemoteObject() constructor.

Wrong. Doing that requires `rmic`.

> 2. Subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and calling the `UnicastRemoteObject(port)` constructor.

Correct. You've left out several cases:

3. Subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and calling the `UnicastRemoteObject(int, RMIClientSocketFactory, RMIServerSocketFactory)` constructor (possibly it is the other way round).
4. *Not* subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and calling the `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote, int)` method.
5. Not subclassing `UnicastRemoteObject` and calling the `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote, int, RMIClientSocketFactory, RMIServerSocketFactory)` method (again it is possibly the other way round).

**EDIT**

```
MyServer()throws RemoteException {
    new UnicastRemoteObject(5000);
}
```

This is not how you call a base class constructor. The correct form is:

```
MyServer() throws RemoteException {
    super(5000);
}
```

This is rather basic.

Comment: I don't think so. Please check, I've included src code now. Moreover if I would have built my own `UnicastRemoteObject` class, `UnicastRemoteObject()` constructor would have been running.

Comment: @ChaitanyaBhardwaj Only if you had provided such a constructor, about which there was zero evidence. Now that you've posted your code, see edit.